# How did Tagon pull off the fireflies trick?

Tags: arthdal-chronicles

In S01E05 of *Arthdal Chronicles*, Tagon is suddenly surrounded by a swarm of fireflies, which illuminate him in the dark of the night; then he speaks as Aramun Haesulla, and the crowd now firmly believes him to be the god's vessel/reincarnation.

Of course, this was all plotted by Tagon to further deepen the people's love of him, and unsettle the Asa clan. His words as "Aramun" were chosen on purpose, and so was the light show, since we saw a glimpse of someone (Taealha?) release the fireflies from a box.

But **how did Tagon ensure the fireflies would come to him?** I'm guessing the most likely explanation is that he used some tasty firefly food, but coating himself in it may be hindered by the heavy white robe he was wearing, and he may not have had access to said robe to coat it before the ceremony (is it provided by the Asas?). Tagon is very well aware of how animals work and how he can use them, as seen when he witnessed the paradise tchitrecs' behaviour of returning to the valley every night and made them carry torches at night (therefore burning Atturad). I'm thus wondering what the fireflies trick was.

---

I tried Googling variations of this question's title, but didn't find anything interesting, although I could only browse English-language results; maybe there's an answer to be found in Korean material.

Comment: Presumably the robes were doctored. Or he had yummy sugary shampoo

Answer (score -1):

When he burned the herbs for his father at the beginning of the funeral ritual it must’ve been To attract the fireflies.? That’s my guess…

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Please note that in order for an answer posted here to be considered a good answer, it should include at some supporting evidence from an official source. If you know of any relevant citations, please [edit] your answer to include them.